# Angular fa-icon change color on hover

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, font-awesome

How would i go about changing style on an fa-icon while hovering over it?
I've tried to add a css class as per the documentation:

```
<fa-icon [icon]="['fas', 'star']" [classes]="['hover-tab-icon']" ></fa-icon>

.hover-tab-icon{
    :hover{
        color: green;
    }
}
```

but none of the changes apply.

Comment: If that is supposed to be LESS or SASS, then you are missing the `&` before `:hover`. What you have creates the selector `.hover-tab-icon :hover`, but what you want is `.hover-tab-icon:hover`

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use the class based icon like this:

```
<i class="fas fa-star"></i>
```

And for applying your style on hover of the icon, simply use the :hover psuedo-selector like this:

```
.fa-star:hover {
  color: green;
}
```